# Based on a declared constraint, the navigation property is required

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0

Im dealing with code first .NET 4 and i'm having trouble with a 1 to 1 relation.

breifing of database:
-POccurrence
  -Id

-POccurrenceRiskAssessment
  -OccurrenceId

in my class Poccurrence I have a property named RiskAsessment, of the type POccurrenceRiskAssessment. Not all POccurrences have riskassessments, so it needs to be nullable.
I tried

```
modelBuilder.Entity<POccurrence>().HasOptional(item => item.RiskAssessment).HasConstraint((o, r) => r.OccurrenceId == o.Id);
```

but that gives me

> The navigation property
>   'RiskAssessment' declared on type
>   'AM.Pris.Classes.POccurrence' has been
>   configured as optional. Based on a
>   declared constraint, the navigation
>   property is required. Either make some
>   dependent key property nullable or
>   configure the navigation as required.

and if i try

```
modelBuilder.Entity<POccurrence>().HasRequired(item => item.RiskAssessment).HasConstraint((o, r) => r.OccurrenceId == o.Id);
```

i get

> A referential integrity constraint
>   violation occurred: A primary key
>   property that is a part of referential
>   integrity constraint cannot be changed
>   when the dependent object is Unchanged
>   unless it is being set to the
>   association's principal object. The
>   principal object must be tracked and
>   not marked for deletion.

and i have no idea what to do. I even tried to delete the real relation in the DB but nothing seems to make any difference. Any idea? I guess its the first try with HasOptional i'm looking for, but how do i make it nullalbe?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered rolling this up into an Table Per Type inheritance scenario where POccurrenceRiskAssessment : POccurrence? That way you only need query POccurrenceRiskAssessment.